# Call a VueJS method inside a component outside 'export default'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to call a function inside 'method' from outside. However, it isn't working.

Github issue reporting the same: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/329

```
vm.test(); // call a function in method, not working
this.vue.test()  // not working
export default {
  methods: {
    test: function() {
      alert('test fuction called');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please remember to mark a comment as accepted.

Answer (score 7):

It is not very clear what the actual goal of the original poster is, however this is how you can call a method on a Vue instance, after creating it:

```
var viewModel = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
  data: {
    msg: "Hello there"
  },
  methods: {
    test: function() {
      alert('test fuction called');
    }
  }
});

viewModel.test();
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Daryn/Lja7pake/3/

If you are exporting a single file component then try this:

example.js

```
<script>
   export default {
    methods: {
      test: function() {
      alert('test fuction called');
     }
    }
   }
</script>
```

main.js

```
<script>
    import Thing from './example.js';
    Thing.test();
</script>
```

Reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Comment: That one looks good. Almost near to it. This is a separate component of vue. There is nothing like 'new Vue....', it starts with 'export default.....'

Comment: I have updated the answer, I did not have time to verify that this works as I am out, but give it a try...

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to achieve is fundamentally flawed. You can't call a method of a component unless you have a reference to an instance of that particular component. In your code, which *particular* component is `vm` referring to?

All you're doing is exporting a Vue component definition from your module; there's no component being instantiated here.

We'll need to see more of your code or a complete explanation of what exactly you're trying to achieve so we can provide an alternative solution. (Why are you trying to call the component's method outside of its definition?)

Comment: how can I export a component as vm?

Comment: This this component meant to be a singleton?

Comment: I've several components. Each component is a like a page where i put it in <router-view>

Comment: You should be broadcasting/dispatching events from the main Vue instance.

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: and no other way other than broadcasting? like: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/329

Comment: You might also want to try Vue's [Gitter](https://gitter.im/vuejs/vue) channel if you need extended help with your specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    ...
  },
  mounted () {
    EventBus.$on(‘EVENT_NAME’, function (payLoad) {
      ...
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I solved that problem.

For the purpose of this demonstration, we create a new project using Vue/CLI. After installation finished, we make the vm exposed to global. Open `src/main.js` and edit like so:

src/main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

var vm = new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');

// Add this line (tambahkan baris berikut):
window.vm = vm;
```

Leave the generated `App.vue` like it is. So the first child of vm (`vm.$children[0]`) is `App.vue`.

We see that `App.vue` have a child. That makes `HelloWorld.vue` component as a grand children of vm (`vm.$children[0].$children[0]`). Knowing this, we can call the methods from outside '`export default`' like this:

src/components/HelloWorld.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <button 
      id="sebuahButton" 
      class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" 
      type="button"
    >Click Me, Jose!</button>
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <!-- and some stuff, vue cli default generated code -->
  <div>
</template>

<script>
(function() {
    // wait for the DOM ready event in plain JavaScript
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
        document.getElementById("sebuahButton").onclick = function() {
            vm.$children[0].$children[0].someAction();
        };
    });
})();

export default {
    name: "HelloWorld",
    props: {
        msg: String
    }
    methods: {
        someAction () {
            // do something (lakukan sesuatu masbro!)
            console.log("It's been called from outer space, Luke!");
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Mind elaborating on why/how this fixes the problem?